# Mongoose get not working ( SchemaType#get(fn) )

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was looking at the API docs of mongoose and found the [get](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-get) option. However it seems not to work for me.

This is the Schema with the get option:

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    get: function (val) {
      return (val.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + val.getDate() + "/" + val.getFullYear() + " " + (val.getHours() + 1) + ":" + (val.getMinutes() + 1) + ":" + (val.getSeconds() + 1);
    }
  }
})
```

This is where I fetch all the documents:

```
var Post = App.model('post')
exports.fetchAll = function (req, res, next) {
  Post.find({}).sort({date: 'desc'}).exec(function (err, posts) {
    if (err) { return next(err) }
    res.json(posts)
  })
}
```

But the results is still the same. On the client side I receive the non formatted string for {{ post.date }}:

```
2015-10-18T07:56:24.606Z
```

I can't figure out why the formatted date string doesn't get returned.

Comment: What is `App`, specifically the `App.model('post')`? Is that an instance of `mongoose`?

Comment: Just a global var containing some helpers. It returns the mongoose Model: global.App = { ...   model: function (name) {
    return require('./../app/models/' + name)
  }, ... }

Comment: Can you add `console.log(val);` before `return (val.getMonth..` to see what val is? I'm just guessing though but it might be string so you should maybe use `val = new Date(val);`

Comment: Just tried it and the get function is never called. Not sure what the problem is then.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can tell mongoose to use the getters when converting the documents to JSON by adding the `getters: true` option to the schema. Mongoose makes this an option, since you may or may not want to have different logic when converting the document to an object (keep the raw date object) or to JSON (formatted date string):

```
var PostSchema = new Schema({
  content: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now,
    get: function (val) {
      return (val.getMonth() + 1) + "/" + val.getDate() + "/" + val.getFullYear() + " " + (val.getHours() + 1) + ":" + (val.getMinutes() + 1) + ":" + (val.getSeconds() + 1);
    }
  }
},
{
    toJSON: {
        getters: true
    }
})
```